# Is it possible to use 2 iPads simultaneously with Sidecar?

Tags: ipad, sidecar

I'd like to use 2 iPads simultaneously as extra monitors for my Mac. When I try to connect a second iPad through Sidecar, it disconnects the first iPad.

Is there a way to override this and use two iPads with Sidecar?

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to use 2 iPads simultaneously with Sidecar?

The current implementation of Sidecar in macOS Catalina and iPadOS 13 doesn't allow using two iPads simultaneously as Sidecar target. While this is not explicitly mentioned by Apple, all the support documents hint towards the conclusion that only a single iPad can be used as a Sidecar target.

- [Use your iPad as a second display for your Mac with Sidecar](https://support.apple.com/HT210380)
- [Sidecar - Sidecar lets you expand your Mac   workspace—and your creativity—with   iPad and Apple Pencil](https://www.apple.com/macos/catalina/docs/Sidecar_Tech_Brief_Oct_2019.pdf)

The primary intent of using Sidecar is not to let you use your iPad as an external display, rather to aid to your productivity.